# Logic App to update On-Prem AD fields on schedule

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-logic-apps, azure-function-app, azure-runbook

I'm developing a Logic App to pull below fields from a different data source and then push them onto On-Prem AD.

```
employeeID
sAMAccountName
mailNickName
givenName
sn
cn
displayName
name
mail
userPrincipalName
telephoneNumber
mobile
personalPager
title
department
company
physcialDeliveryOfficeName
streetAddress
l
photo
manager
division
employeeType
extensionAttribute1
extensionAttribute2
extensionAttribute5
```

I know it's easier to update AAD but there doesn't seem to be any option to sync AAD back to On-Prem AD.
I've been researching and found that I can go with below options:

- Runbook in Azure Automation OR Azure PowerShell Function App.

Can someone point me through to right direction which one is easier option to go with or have any other recommendations that these two?

Comment: You should use Microsoft Identity Manager for this (formerly known as ForeFront Identity Manager).  That's what is was designed for.  Pulling LDAP-type or LDAP-like data from disparate data sources and pushing it into Active Directory or vice versa.

Comment: @T-Heron, can you please write an answer to that?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was actually posted in comment. Posting it here for awareness for others:
You should use Microsoft Identity Manager for this (formerly known as ForeFront Identity Manager). That's what is was designed for. Pulling LDAP-type or LDAP-like data from disparate data sources and pushing it into Active Directory or vice versa